# How to get SQLITE database file to sync in DropBox?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, dropbox, nsfilemanager

I am working on an IPad app.Here I want to upload whole database file to dropbox.I searched on google by but didnot found appropriate solution.I used the following code to create database.

```
-(BOOL) createDatabaseFile
{
     NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL successMsg = YES;
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

// Build the path to the database file
self.detaildatabasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@`"Database.sql"`]];
// Check For Existence of the database file
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:self.detaildatabasePath])
{
    //File Exists At The Path
}
else
{
    //Since file is not available at the path create a Database File
    successMsg = [filemgr createFileAtPath:self.detaildatabasePath contents:[NSData data] attributes:nil];
}
return successMsg;
}
```

So how can I get my "Database.sql" file.Please dont treat it as duplicate question.I had wasted a day for googling but didnot find solution..Please guide me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you post code about creating the database file? You need to start with the Dropbox SDK - https://www.dropbox.com/developers. BTW - the code you posted does not create a database file. If anything, it created an empty file that can't be used as a database file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload file to Dropbox you need Dropbox SDKs - https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/ios (how to add Dropbox.framework to your project)

Then you can upload file:

```
-(void) createBackupInDropbox {
    NSString *filename = @"backup.sqlite"; //File name in DropBox
    NSString *destDir = @"/backups"; //Destination path in DropBox
    NSString *fromPath = @"..."; //local path to your DB file
    /*
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     fromPath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my_database.sqlite"];
    */

    [[self restClient] deletePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", destDir, filename]]; //delete file if you need to replace it
    [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir
                    withParentRev:nil fromPath:fromPath];
}
```

To control uploading process:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadedFile:(NSString*)destPath
              from:(NSString*)srcPath metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {
    NSLog(@"File uploaded successfully to path: %@", metadata.path);
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error {
    [waitIndicator dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"File upload failed with error - %@", error);
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadProgress:(CGFloat)progress forFile:(NSString *)destPath from:(NSString *)srcPath
{

}
```

And restClient method:

```
- (DBRestClient *)restClient {
    if (!restClient) {
        restClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
        restClient.delegate = self;
    }
    return restClient;
}
```